# Passing temporary data back to hidden field in Yii

Tags: php, forms, yii, hidden

I'm trying to pass a temporary data from my form to my model. My form has a hidden data in it, but it does not get any values from my model.

My form is

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'fieldName'); ?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
```

I threw in  the data for my hidden field using JQuery, and then I proceeed to validate my form.

```
public function rules() 
{
    return array(       
        array('name, email, subject, phone, body', 'required','message' => '{attribute} Required'),
        array('resume', 'file', 'types'=>'txt,pdf,doc,docx', 'maxSize'=>2097152, 'tooLarge'=>'File has to be smaller than 2MB','allowEmpty'=>false),
        array('email', 'email'),
    );
}
```

Whenever the validation hits an exception, it returns all of the `$_POST` data I inputted except the data I sent from the hidden form.

How do I get the `$_POST` so it gets back to the hidden form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:
The **attribute** must be **declared** as **public** in the **model**.

```
public $fieldName;
```

Add in **rules()** of **Model** the field with a **safe mode** *array('fieldName','safe')* :

```
public function rules() 
{
    return array(       
        array('name, email, subject, phone, body', 'required','message' => '{attribute} Required'),
        array('resume', 'file', 'types'=>'txt,pdf,doc,docx', 'maxSize'=>2097152, 'tooLarge'=>'File has to be smaller than 2MB','allowEmpty'=>false),
        array('email', 'email'),
        array('fieldName','safe'), // Add the custom field to 'safe' mode.
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'fieldName' part of the model/table? If not and it is just a custom property declared in the model, then try setting it as 'safe'

Comment: so will I add it in the array? array('fieldName','safe');

Comment: Yes, in rules function.